# How do I prevent the Google bot from sending queries to my mixpanel?

Tags: google-tag-manager, mixpanel

How do I prevent the Google bot from sending queries to my mixpanel?

I tried to exclude it via Google tag manager, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel JS script filters out by default the main search bots.

For other bots, you can add a script which looks at the UserAgent and filters out the ones you are not interested in.

Read more in this [Mixpanel thread](https://community.mixpanel.com/data-management-10/exclude-bot-activity-web-javascript-articles-from-the-archive-2774).

Answer (score 0):

Eric here from Mixpanel Support. That’s a great question! By default, the following bots are filtered out by the Mixpanel JavaScript library:

Yahoo! Slurp

bingbot/2.0

Googlebot/2.1

Baiduspider/2.0

YandexBot/3.0

That being said, it’s possible to set up some code to filter out these users. Find the user agent information of the individual accessing the site. Look for the word “bot” anywhere in the user agent information. If you find “bot,” set the $ignore property to true.

If you can, identify a common pattern in the bots to block them all in one shot by filtering out any interaction with your site that comes from a web framework that is not a consumer-facing browser. As an example, for GTM bots, this code would look like this:

var userAgentBotTest = navigator.userAgent; mixpanel.register({"User Agent": userAgentBotTest});
if (/(Mozilla/4.0)/i.test(userAgentBotTest)) { mixpanel.register({"$ignore": true}); }

If you implement this code, you will block all userAgents with "Mozilla/4.0" in the userAgent. This does include some older browsers, but modern browsers such as Chrome, Safari, and Firefox will never include this in their userAgent strings. See a common list of bot [userAgents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?typ=Crawler) and [common bot browsers](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?typ=Browser). If this does not work, you can start tracking this userAgent going forward so you can find the common pattern among all of the bots crawling your site. Note $ignore must have a string or at least be set to true, or else the event will fire.

For example, if I have '$ignore': '', the event will still fire since it's an empty string. '$ignore': false will also fire the event.  Mixpanel data is written once, and read forever, which means once a data point is written to a project, there isn't a way to selectively remove it. However, there are a few other options:

1. [Hide the Events](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004567926) in question from the UI.
2. If the bot activity has a distinguishing Property value, create a [Custom Event](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004562246-How-can-I-track-cohorts-or-custom-groups-of-users-) that excludes all activity with that value.

Hope that helps!